# Load error with my gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I built a gem using

```
$ gem build <gemspec>
```

It got built successfully and I successfully installed it.

but when I do the following:

```
$ irb -rubygems
irb(main):003:0 require 'xxxx'
```

I get the following error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- xxxx
 from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'gem_original_require'
 from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your `.gemspec` file as well?

It's quite possible that you haven't included the files in the `.files` array. For example,

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # Other specifications
  s.files       = ["bin/google", "lib/google.rb", "lib/google/utils.rb"]
  s.files      += ["LICENSE.md", "README.md", "google.gemspec"]
end
```

Comment: If i have runtime dependencies in my gemspec. How do i install that gem. Do i still use: $gem install abc.gem ?

Comment: Runtime dependencies are other gems that your gem needs when it runs. If you've already specified them in your gemspec, their installation will be taken care of when you install your gem. However, your gem needs to include the files you wrote for it. The `.files` array is a laundry list of the files that should be included in your gem. It's essentially telling the `gem build` command that "these files need to be included in the gem," much like when you select which files to zip up into a ZIP file.